# Set pod IP using Minikube (k8s) + Calico Plugin

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, calico

I'm doing some tests with minikube + calico plugin to see if I can set the pod IP on pod creation.

I've open the minikube proxy and sent:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Pod",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "pod2",
        "annotations": {
            "cni.projectcalico.org/ipAddrs": "[\"172.18.0.50\"]"
        }
    },
    "spec": {
        "containers": [
            {
                "name": "hello-node",
                "image": "k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4",
                "ports": [
                    {
                        "containerPort": 8081
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But it seems the annotation was ignored. The pod was created using another IP:

```
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP           NODE   
pod1                              1/1     Running   0          36s     172.18.0.8   minikube
pod2                              1/1     Running   0          6s      172.18.0.9   minikube
```

I've checked the `10-calico.conflist` file, the plugin is set to use `calico-ipam`.

What am I missing?

---

Edit:
Calico version:

```
Client Version:    v3.14.0
Git commit:        c97876ba
Cluster Version:   v3.14.0
Cluster Type:      k8s,kdd,bgp,kubeadm
```

Output of `kubectl get po --all-namespaces -o wide`:

```
NAMESPACE              NAME                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    IP           NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
default                hello-minikube-64b64df8c9-fd5vz              1/1     Running   1          70m    172.18.0.7   minikube   <none>           <none>
default                pod1                                         1/1     Running   0          67m    172.18.0.8   minikube   <none>           <none>
default                pod2                                         1/1     Running   0          66m    172.18.0.9   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system            calico-kube-controllers-789f6df884-msvzm     1/1     Running   2          152m   172.18.0.6   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system            calico-node-5l2vm                            1/1     Running   1          152m   172.17.0.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system            calicoctl                                    1/1     Running   1          121m   172.17.0.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system            coredns-66bff467f8-8hmpv                     1/1     Running   3          28h    172.18.0.5   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system            coredns-66bff467f8-xwrpj                     1/1     Running   3          28h    172.18.0.3   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system            etcd-minikube                                1/1     Running   2          27h    172.17.0.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-apiserver-minikube                      1/1     Running   2          27h    172.17.0.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-minikube             1/1     Running   3          28h    172.17.0.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-proxy-wq29b                             1/1     Running   3          28h    172.17.0.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system            kube-scheduler-minikube                      1/1     Running   3          28h    172.17.0.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kube-system            storage-provisioner                          1/1     Running   5          28h    172.17.0.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper-84bfdf55ff-kj4t2   1/1     Running   3          28h    172.18.0.4   minikube   <none>           <none>
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-696dbcc666-qxc78        1/1     Running   5          28h    172.18.0.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
```

Comment: could you please share the result of `kubectl get po --all-namespaces -o wide` and calico version?

Comment: sure @hariK I'll edit the question as the output is too long for a comment

Comment: can you try `cni.projectcalico.org/ipAddrs": "[\"172.18.0.10\"]` with this annotation or IP address between `172.18.0.0 - 172.18.0.10`? Also please share `calicoctl get ipppool -o wide`

Comment: pod3 was successfully created with IP 172.18.0.10 `pod3                              1/1     Running   0          13s   172.18.0.10   minikube   <none>           <none>
`

Comment: output of get ippool: `NAME                  CIDR            NAT    IPIPMODE   VXLANMODE   DISABLED   SELECTOR   
default-ipv4-ippool   10.244.0.0/16   true   Always     Never       false      all()`

Comment: how did you start minikube or what's the command you used?

Comment: I started it with `minikube start --driver=docker`

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Usually the pod IP addresses are a very hidden implementation detail; the only place where you use them even indirectly is via a headless service, and then typically only for StatefulSets.

Comment: I know in most contexts it would be considered an anti-pattern, but I'm trying to meet a very specific requirement.

Comment: @AFMeirelles Follow below steps
`minikube start --network-plugin=cni --host-only-cidr=192.168.0.0/16`
`kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/calico.yaml`
`kubectl create -f pod.json`